# How to apply animation to setBackground color property of view in Android?

Tags: android-animation, material-design

I am trying to implement following and edit text where when validation fails, the line of edit text changes color to red and color change is animated from center out to edges.

I have the view setup as, hide edit text bottom line, added view below edit text to show the line

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fpet_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:errorEnabled="false"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/fpet_edit_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColorHighlight="@color/blue"
      android:background="@null"
      android:textColorLink="@color/blue"
      android:paddingTop="5dp"
      android:textSize="18dp"
      />


  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fpet_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/fpet_text_input_layout"
    android:background="@color/grey"></ImageView>
```

I have tried multiple ways but still not able to get in exactly right. Here is what I have tried so far

1. Use scale animation and start animation before doing set background. But in this case, the line is getting redrawn instead of just changing color
2. I have tried using value animator but I can't find a proper way to apply custom animation instead of fade in behavior.

   ```
   Integer colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.grey);
   Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(color);
   ValueAnimator colorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(),      colorFrom, colorTo);
   colorAnimator.setDuration(1000);
   colorAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()     {

   @Override
   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
      underLine.setBackgroundColor((Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue());
   }

   });
   colorAnimator.start();
   ```

[image]

I would really appreciate any help with this, I can add more code for what I have tried, I didn't want to make the question too long. Thnanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to achieve effect which you'd like.

```
public class AnimatedEditText extends EditText {
    private Paint paint;
    private Rect rect;

    public AnimatedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        rect = new Rect();
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    public void playAnimation() {
        rect.top = getMeasuredHeight() - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.line_offset);
        rect.bottom = getMeasuredHeight();
        rect.left = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        rect.right = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("left", rect.left, 0), PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("right", rect.right, getMeasuredWidth()));
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                rect.left = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("left");
                rect.right = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("right");
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(500);
        animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: works like charm! Thank you so much, this was very helpful!